# How to add a new key value pair to existing key value pair from list of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a parent-key and its value is a dict. I want to extract a key,val pair from a list of dict.

given:

```
{"Premier" : {}}
```

I want to extract:

```
 all_compseasons = content: [
    {
        label: "2019/20",
        id: 274
    },
    {
        label: "2018/19",
        id: 210
    }]
```

So to get:

```
{"Premier" : 
    {"2019/20" : 274, 
    "2018/19" : 210
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a good way to do it. I've tried below given other examples of the problem, but doesn't work.

```
compseasons = {}
for comp in all_compseasons:
    competition_id = 'Premier'
    index = competition_id
    compseasons[index]comp['label'] = comp['id']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very close. Dictionary keys need to be referenced with surrounding `[]`, so `comp['label']` should be `[comp['label']]`. You can also just use the given dictionary `{"Premier" : {}}` instead of creating a new one with `compseasons = {}`, but either will give you the same result.

**Working solution:**

```
d = {"Premier": {}}

all_compseasons = [{"label": "2019/20", "id": 274}, {"label": "2018/19", "id": 210}]

for comp in all_compseasons:
    d["Premier"][comp["label"]] = comp["id"]

print(d)
# {'Premier': {'2019/20': 274, '2018/19': 210}}
```

Comment: The reason for the structure I have tried is because the real problem that is the be solved covers multiple parent-keys that has to be set before appending the child-pairs. Thank you for taking your time to provide a solution, will try to implement it on the problem I have, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake in how you declared `compseasons` and how you are accessing the value of `premier` key which is also a dictionary.

Declaring `compseasons = {"Premier" : {}}` will not give you KeyError when you are trying to access it via `compseasons[index]` since `Premier` has already been inserted as a key.

Second, since your value of `Premier` itself is a dictionary, you should access the inner key enclosed in `[]` which would translate to `compseasons[index][comp['label']] = comp['id']`.

```
all_compseasons = [
{
    'label': "2019/20",
    'id': 274
},
{
    'label': "2018/19",
    'id': 210
}]

compseasons = {"Premier" : {}}

for comp in all_compseasons:
    competition_id = 'Premier'
    index = competition_id
    compseasons[index][comp['label']] = comp['id']
```